# What is the best solution for a dynamic component loading method for big applications in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular2, even though I managed to build an average sized application on angular 2. now my problem is I noticed every file (components) loaded on initial loading of the website. I just want to load corresponding files of each page (when router load page). I know lib called lazy loader for angular 1,

So my questions is What is the best solution for a dynamic component loading method for big applications in angular2.
Thank you

Comment: https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-declarative-lazy-loading-7071d1f203ee

Comment: Angular 2+ has lazy loading [Here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/modules/lazy-loading-module)